# C++: OpenMP: Copying function pointers for multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, function-pointers, openmp

I have a parallelized fitting program (parallelized with OpenMP) that takes the function that it has to fit using function pointers. I've been facing problems, and eventually I found out that I pass the same function pointer to the class that does the fitting, which conflicts with the others and produces messy results.

How can I "copy" function pointers to make them thread-safe, or in other words, to have threads not conflict with each other?

The function I'm pointing too looks like this:

```
void function(const Real t, RealArray &a, Real &y)
{
#pragma omp critical //if I remove this line, the catastrophe happens and I get wrong results
    {
    if(t < FIDLength)
    {
        y = ...;
    }
}
```

And the class in each thread is constructed as follows:

```
FitClass fit(DSxAxis1.size(),initialValues_param.size(),function,function2,constraints3D);
```

function and function2 are function pointers. They both are used the same way.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not about the functions pointers themselves - but rather, whether they share data.

Comment: All threads are parametrised with the same function pointer... so they retrieve the value of the function from the same address... I don't understand what you mean with sharing data.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any code. But you should check if you have any data-sharing that's causing harmful race conditions.

Comment: OK, I'll add some code for the function pointer. The sharing is happening, as far as I think, because of the function pointer, it being a pointer means that all threads are checking the same memory zone. I think it's happening like that; not sure though.

Comment: The fact that the critical section "fixes" it is a clear sign that you do indeed have a malicious data-race somewhere in the function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't get your point. Could you please explain? I'm thinking also of using functors... perhaps this would help, but would require me to change the whole structure of my fitting class.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing

Comment: Yeah sure, this is what's happening. But how can I "copy" function pointers in to a different region in memory, so that different instances of the same function won't conflict with itself in different threads?

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my first comment. Functions pointers can't "conflict". It's the data that it is accessing that is conflicting. For example: Check the parameters that you are passing. Make sure they aren't sharing the same data.

Comment: The function evaluates a pure math function... some exponents and some sines... how could this share data?! it takes data from &a, does some math to it, and saves the result to y. Is there anyway this could conflict with anything else shared?

Comment: You cannot make a copy of a function. There is only one code instance in memory per function and it doesn't matter if you call it by name directly or through function pointer. It is the code inside the function that does something bad. Check for shared data access, e.g. global variables or shared arrays.

Comment: the math functions may use auxiliary variables which are shared.

Comment: That's a good point, Walter. I'm trying now to use templatised functors. If that works, this would confirm that point.

Answer (score 1):

I used a semi-functor and it worked. So my fitting class has now a template parameter that contains the function, its derivatives and other stuff. And this worked properly.

Result: Not all std functions are thread-safe.

Comment: Which math functions are you using? There are some that use globals. I believe `gamma()` uses globals, I'm not sure though.

Comment: cosines, sines and exponents.